# Create unique constraint with nvl in Oracle

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

How can I create unique constraint when I need to treat null values as equals.

For

> alter table T1 add constraint T1_UN
>   unique (nvl(C1, ' '))

i get

```
 ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

points on nvl

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT NULL` seems like a better idea, but you could make a function-based index unique:

```
 create unique index idx_t1 on t1 (nvl(C1, ' '));
```

Comment: Small sidenote: that would treat a null as a space, and as a result you would not be able to insert a single space in the column anymore. Depending on the expected data this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, but I think that was the intent expressed in the original statement in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the column `NOT NULL`.

The nature of `NULL` is that it is never equal to anything. Hence every `NULL` value in your column is already `UNIQUE` in a way. It doesn't make sense to include them in a `UNIQUE` key like you want to. The reason why you want to do it is probably an existing data integrity problem. So to make the column `NOT NULL`, you might have to migrate `NULL` values to something else, first...

Note: You can make the column just simply `UNIQUE`. Then you can have several `NULL` values as described above...

Comment: I can't make it not null because it should contains null values also.

Comment: At most a single `NULL` value? Why?

Comment: Replacement with not null will leads to a lot of changes in codebase. It is possible to create nvl index, as I know. I need some quick workaround for my case.